# Why does the compiler give the error "invalid conversion from const int * to int*?"

Tags: c++

The following is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printArrayPointer(const int arr[], int n){
  for (int *j = arr; j < arr + n; ++j) {
    cout << *j << " ";
  }
}

int main()
{
   int arr[5] = {0,1,3,3,4};
   printArrayPointer(arr, 5);
   return 0;
}
```

The compiler gives the following error

> invalid conversion from const int * to int *

I'm not modifying `arr`, so why is there an error?

Comment: `const int arr[]` ; `int *j = arr`. You may be not, but const-correctness does not care.

Comment: by assigning to non-constant, you would potentially allow the constant data to be modified through `j`, even if it is not the case here. That's violating the contract of the function interface.

In your case, it's easily fixable since you still honor the contract by not modifying the data. Just fix it by adding `const` qualifier.
  
    for (const int *j = arr; j < arr + n; ++j)